# \counterwithin{figure}{chapter} is not working

Tags: floats, numbering

I haven't used this forum before. But i'm trying to numbering the equations, figures and tabels as 1.1, 2.1 and 3.1. My document class is memoir as you can see. I have trying the following:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}
\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}
```

and

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
```

and

```
\letcountercounter{figure}{table} 
\letcountercounter{equation}{table}
```

but non of them are working. I'm wondering if some of the packages blokes the others packages. I hope some of you can help me.

The following below is my preamble packages.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,a4paper,11pt,article,twoside]{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% PACKAGES %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{maplestd2e} 
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode} 
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{float}   
\usepackage[danish]{babel}                              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{array}              
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}
\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}
%\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
%\numberwithin{table}{chapter}
%\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
%\letcountercounter{figure}{table}
%\letcountercounter{equation}{table}
\usepackage{listings}                      
\begin{lstlisting}
\usepackage{ulem}                
\usepackage{lscape}                         
(\begin{landscape})
\usepackage{siunitx}                        
\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage{wrapfig}                        
\usepackage{subfig}                         
\usepackage[square,sort]{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{n}{,}{,}         
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}               
\usepackage{graphicx}                       
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[danish=quotes]{csquotes}        
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{rotating}
\captionsetup{margin=25pt,font={footnotesize,sf},format=hang}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}                       
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
%\usepackage[grey,utopia]{quotchap}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. See [this guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for help.

Comment: This is not a full minimal example. Are you by any chance using `\mainmatter` later on?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me if I comment out the `\begin{}` lines as well as the `maplestd2e` and `mcode` `\usepackage`s.

Comment: @erik: Which `\begin` lines? As far as I can see, the `mcode` package does not change the counting/numbering at all.

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence In amongst the `\usepackage`s are `\begin{lstlisting}` and `(\begin{landscape})`. If I comment out these lines and the two packages I don't have (`mcode` and `maplestd2e`) the numbering works fine.

Comment: @erik: Oh my, I did not notice those weird lines. You're right!