# Per-chapter counter for floats not working

Tags: floats, captions

I am having problems with changing the format of float captions. I want my code to add a per-chapter counter for tables, figures and equations (i.e. "fig. 3.1" instead of "fig. 15" for instance).

I used this before, but I started using a new document format, and for some reason it's just not working. It works for equations, but not for tables and figures.

I'm using `\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}` to do it, and I also tried with `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}`.

Does anyone have any experience with why this wouldn't work?

This is my preamble (`\numberwithin{}{}` is under % References)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,article,11pt]{memoir}

% Basic setup
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Input encoding - Depending on editor
\usepackage{lmodern} % Modern LaTeX font
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Language package
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Hyphenation
\usepackage{fix-cm} % Fix for cm
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Debugging text
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx} % To handle pictures
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Image path
\usepackage{xcolor} % To define colors
\usepackage{tikz} % Graphical tool
\definecolor{ase_blue}{RGB}{10,55,136}

% Tables
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{changepage} % Changes margins locally
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{longtable}

% Math
\usepackage{mathtools} % To use \eqref
\usepackage{calc}% Auto calculate
\usepackage{sansmath,subfig} % Gives a warning because subfig loads caption
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% References
\usepackage{varioref} % Smarter references
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={<The authors>}, pdftitle={<The title>},pdfsubject={<The subject>}}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage{url} % Use of urls in the text
\urlstyle{tt}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[numbered]{mcode}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\newcommand{\stoptocwriting}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-5}}}
\newcommand{\resumetocwriting}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\arabic{tocdepth}}}}

% Caption setup
\captionsetup{font={small,rm}}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{font={small,rm}}

% Margin control
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1.2}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}

% Frontpage
\usepackage{color,soul} % Letterspace package
\sodef\an{}{0.05em}{.5em plus.6em}{1em plus.1em minus.1em}
\newcommand\stext[1]{\an{\scshape#1}}
\newcommand{\logoHuge}{\fontsize{0.55cm}{0.8cm}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\SuperHuge}{\fontsize{1.2cm}{1.8cm}\selectfont}

% Pagestyle
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
\makepagestyle{ase_report}
\makeevenhead{ase_report}{\textsc{Auto-OMA on Hexapod}}{}{}
\makeoddhead{ase_report}{}{}{\small\scshape\leftmark}
\makeheadrule{ase_report}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenfoot{ase_report}{\small\rmfamily\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{ase_report}{}{}{\small\rmfamily\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}

\makepagestyle{intro}
\makeevenhead{intro}{\textsc{Auto-OMA on Hexapod}}{}{}
\makeoddhead{intro}{}{}{\small\scshape\leftmark}
\makeheadrule{intro}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenfoot{intro}{\small\rmfamily\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{intro}{}{}{\small\rmfamily\thepage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{ase_report}{%
  \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum \value{secnumdepth} > 1
      \if@mainmatter % 
      \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
      \fi
      \fi
      ##1}{}}%
  \renewcommand\tocmark{\markboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}}%
  \renewcommand\lofmark{\markboth{\listfigurename}{\listfigurename}}%
  \renewcommand\lotmark{\markboth{\listtablename}{\listtablename}}%
  \renewcommand\bibmark{\markboth{\bibname}{\bibname}}%
  \renewcommand\indexmark{\markboth{\indexname}{\indexname}}%
  \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{##1}}%
  \renewcommand\subsectionmark[1]{\markright{##1}}%
  \renewcommand\subsubsectionmark[1]{\markright{##1}}}

\copypagestyle{plain}{ase_report}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\small\rmfamily\thepage}

\pagestyle{ase_report}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}

% Chapter style
\makechapterstyle{ase_chapterstyle}{
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-20pt}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{0.5cm}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\scshape\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{
    \flushleft
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill,color=ase_blue] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
      \draw[color=white] (1cm,1cm) node {\chapnumfont\thechapter}(0.5cm,0.5cm );
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\scshape\huge\color{black}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \raggedright\chaptitlefont\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\raggedright##1}}}

\chapterstyle{ase_chapterstyle}

% Section style
\newcommand{\ruledsec}[1]{%
\Large\scshape\raggedright #1
\color{ase_blue}\rule[15pt]{\textwidth}{1.0pt}} % Section with ruler
\setsecheadstyle{\ruledsec} % Define section head style

\setfloatlocations{figure}{htp}
\setfloatlocations{table}{htp}

% Subsection style
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{2} % Depth numbering

\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\scshape\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\scshape\raggedright}

\setsechook{\hangsecnum} % Hang the section number in margin
\setsubsechook{\defaultsecnum} % Don't do this on the subsections
\setsubsubsechook{\defaultsecnum}
\setaftersecskip{5pt} % Default skip between the section and text

% Table of contents
\raggedbottomsectiontrue % The page may not be strected on page breaks
\setsecnumdepth{section} % Set section depth in the TOC
\maxsecnumdepth{section} % Max of section depth in the TOC
\settocdepth{section} % Up to and including subsection
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\small\scshape}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\small\scshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\small\scshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpagefont}{\small\scshape}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt} % Space from chapters
%\chapterprecistoc{Text in TOC}

\addto\captionsenglish{
  \renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{Chapter{\space}}
  \renewcommand*{\cftfigurename}{Fig.{\space}}
  \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
  \renewcommand*{\abstractname}{Abstract}
  \renewcommand*{\listfigurename}{List{\space}of{\space}Figures}
  \renewcommand*{\listtablename}{List{\space}of{\space}Tables}
  \renewcommand*{\appendixtocname}{Appendices}
  \renewcommand*{\appendixpagename}{Appendices}
}

% Hide appendices from TOC:
\newcounter{oldtocdepth}
\newcommand{\hidefromtoc}{\setcounter{oldtocdepth}{\value{tocdepth}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}}}
\newcommand{\unhidefromtoc}{
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\value{oldtocdepth}}}}
\usepackage{bookmark}

 \usepackage{nomencl}
 \makenomenclature
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We always appreciate minimal (!!!) working (so with `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) examples. Please make your code fragment one of those.

Comment: You are breaking a number of rules here: [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) is a versatile class that provides many internal functions typically supplied by external packages. For example, there's no need to use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig).

Comment: Agree, make this minimal to this problem only, and make it complete. My guess: you are using `\mainmatter ` and forgot that this resets  any counters within

Comment: \counterwithin cause the figure counter to reset, but you still need to redefine \thefigure.  (Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232433/counterwithinfigurechapter-is-not-working - which was also unclear).

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise I broke rules with this question. The reason I included my entire preamble is because I don't know where exactly the problem is, so I figured it could be anywhere in the preamble.
@Werner, for some reason, if I remove subfig and fancyhdr in my preamble, I get errors.

Comment: @daleif Removing \frontmatter and \mainmatter solves the problem. I thought those were the cause of Roman numerals in the beginning, arabic numerals in the main text and letters in the appendix, but that still seems to work when removing those, so I'm not sure what they're good for anyway.
Thanks a lot for your solution!

Comment: Just move them after mainmatter. Frontmatter sets the numbering to single digits. Chances are you have no figures or tables in frontmatter. Mainmatter sets it back to normal, but they do not record what the chosen value was (as most use the default). And now you also know why we keep asking  for full minimal examples

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot! I'll make sure to include full and minimal examples from now on.

Comment: @daleif Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is actually twofold. (1) you are using the `article` option, (2) you are using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. Since `\frontmatter` actually removes any dominant counter from from for example `\thefigure`, any adjustments, in the preamble, to counter dominance will be be overwritten by `\frontmatter` (for good reason, there are no dominant counters available in the front matter).

When `\mainmatter` comes along, it will normally run `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}` to bring back dominance again. But it does not do that under the `article` option, as the `article` option is an emulation of the `article` class behaviour, aka consecutive numbering.

The easiest solution is to patch an internal component in `\mainmatter`, such that the article branch reissues counter dominance:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@smemmain}{\ifartopt}{\ifartopt\@memmain@floats}{\typeout{patch
    done}}{\typeout{patch failed}}
\makeatother
```

A few other comments:

There is no reason to load `fancyhdr` as you don't use it.

The `\makepsmarks{ase_report}{` can be done using much simpler code, see `\createmark` and `\createplainmark`.